# Python Flask dynamic images

Tags: python, flask

I am currently working with Flask and python on a raspberry pi. I have made a html template which gets some info from the python script. I can also get an image to show, but only if it is hardcoded in like src='5.jpg'. When I try to do it dynamically it does not work. Can anyone help me with how to set it in the python file

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{{side}}.jpg')}}" />
```

This is the one that does not work if I change the {{side}} with 5 it works. I know that I am sending the {{side}} to the html since it outputs it on the line over

Comment: Can share the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, it's just that the image does not show up

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='{{side}}.jpg')}}" />
```

Jinja2 [does not support](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/623) nested variables inside of variables. Jinja2 cannot resolve {{side}} inside of your {{url_for}}. Your browser is probably trying to find an image called `{{side}}.jpg` to serve, but it cannot.